# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'timetuple'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert a pandas column DateTime (UTC) which seems like this df_1['MESS_DATUM'] = 202209250000 to unixtime. My code looks like this:

```
df_1['MESS_DATUM'] = calendar.timegm(df_1['MESS_DATUM'].timetuple())

print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(df_1['MESS_DATUM']))
```

But I am getting this error "**AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'timetuple'**".
I have used the below method as well but my time is in UTC which is why it is not giving me the right unix time I guess:

```
df_1['MESS_DATUM'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['MESS_DATUM'])
(df_1['MESS_DATUM'] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s') 
print(df_1['MESS_DATUM'])  #it gives me the following datetime in unix form
1970-01-01 00:03:22.209252150
```

I tried the above method for a single datetime string as shown below and it works but for the whole datetime column it gives me this value 1970-01-01 00:03:22.209252150

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2022-09-15 13:30:00'])
# calculate unix datetime
dates = (dates - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
print(dates) # Int64Index([1663248600], dtype='int64')
```

I tried this method as well which gives me again the wrong unixtime

```
df_1['MESS_DATUM'] = pd.DatetimeIndex ( df_1['MESS_DATUM'] ).astype ( np.int64 )/1000000
print(df_1['MESS_DATUM']) 
202.209252 # this is the unixtime I get
```

Any helpful solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the value using the datetime library;

```
d = 202209250000
import datetime 
datetime.datetime.strptime(str(d),'%Y%m%d%H%M').timestamp()
```

Converting the column can be done using using df.apply;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'MESS_DATUM': [202209250000,202209260000,202209270000]})
df['MESS_DATUM'] = df['MESS_DATUM'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x),'%Y%m%d%H%M').timestamp())
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it worked.                                                                                  
df_1['MESS_DATUM'] = pd.DataFrame(df_1['MESS_DATUM'])
df_1['MESS_DATUM'] = df_1['MESS_DATUM'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x),'%Y%m%d%H%M').timestamp())
print(df_1['MESS_DATUM'])

Comment: You want to avoid native Python's datetime if working with pandas, plus the `apply` means an unnecessary iteration in Python instead of letting underlying C-code do the heavy lifting. Use `df['MESS_DATUM'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MESS_DATUM'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d%H%M')`.